# Apache Camel Include And Exclude File Patterns

Tags: spring, apache-camel

Hi I'm using Apache Camel & Spring for importing files. I need to include only `.zip` files but i want to exclude `_ACK.zip` files. Is there a way to achieve this?

this is as far as ive gotten
`&exclude=.*_ACK.zip&move=$simple{file:name.noext}_ACK.$simple{file:name.ext}`

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks fine imo. What's the behavior you get now?

Comment: If there is a file named test.abc then camel pics up that too. i need camel to pickup only .zip files except _ACK.zip files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the exclude option as it is and additonally add the include=*.zip option.

Comment: It should be "include=.*.zip". Otherwise, it will throw a regex error.